# How to plot regression line with ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, regression

I am trying to put two regression lines into the same plot. I can do it by using the code below but with the same color of line:

```
model1 <- glm(species~logarea, family=poisson, data=fish)
model2 <- glm.nb(species~logarea, data=fish)

plot(species~logarea,data=fish)
lines(fitted(model1)[order(logarea)]~sort(logarea),data=fish)
lines(fitted(model2)[order(logarea)]~sort(logarea),data=fish)
```

I am thinking to use ggplot to replicate above plot so I can display different line with different color. But I could not figure out how to do it.

I only finished the first step which is drawing the scatter plot, but don't know how to add lines on it.

```
ggplot(fish,aes(fish$logarea,fish$SPECIES))+geom_point()
```

I did some search and I understand that I can use geom_smooth(method = "glm") to generate regression line. But it seems it is not based on the model I built.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `geom_line(aes(y=fitted_datas))`, for instance like this :

```
data("mtcars")
library(ggplot2)
model <- glm(mpg~hp, family=poisson, data=mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(hp,mpg))+geom_point()+geom_line(aes(y=fitted(model)))
```

Results :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Arault. It works well on my code.

Answer (score 4):

You can fit the models directly in `geom_smooth`.  In this case, you'll need to give extra arguments to the fitting method using the `method.args` argument to define the family for the `glm`.

Here is an example, adding different colors per model type.  I use `se = FALSE` to remove the confidence intervals.

```
ggplot(fish,aes(logarea, SPECIES)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = poisson), aes(color = "poisson"), se = FALSE) +
    geom_smooth(method = MASS::glm.nb, aes(color = "NB"), se = FALSE)
```